# Add tinymce buttons to caption textarea in media uploader

Tags: jquery, uploads, javascript, media, tinymce

I want to add some basic tinymce buttons ( Bold, italic, underline ) to caption textarea in media uploader in WordPress. (Shown in attached image)

I dig a little bit into wordpress core in media.php and media-editor.js file in wp-includes but not getting any hint. Please help me, how can I add it.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I tried to get my head around this yesterday and I came pretty close solving this issue. But i gave up in the end, cause it was getting too complicated, when start thinking about all the tools, that you want to include/exclude. If you still wanna do this on your own, these two filters are your friend: `attachment_fields_to_edit` & `attachment_fields_to_save`.

I now solved with the great [acf plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/wysiwyg-editor/). I just placed a new wysiwyg editor into the attachment page and hide the original caption field via css.